# How to adjust an array of hours to a preferred timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

So a little context, I have an array of 24 arrays -- one for every hour in the day.

So midnight, 0 index, would be `[133.00, 234.00]` which would indicate 133 actions from 12 - 1230 and 234 actions between 1230 - 1am.

I need to adjust these indexed arrays to account for the user's timezone in a browser with JS, so that if the user is in New York the 0 index (midnight in the user's home turf) is displayed in China's offset (12pm tomorrow, from user's perspective).

I've been trying to think of a solution, I have a simple function for what I've been able to think of

```
function offsetHourIndex(hourIndex, dataCenterTimeZone) {
  let userTime = new Date().setHour(hourIndex)
  return moment(userTime).tz(dataCenterTimeZone).hour();
}
```

How reliable would this approach be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach has a few problems:

- You are assuming that the current date in the local time zone is the correct date for the target time zone.  Most of the time, there are two dates active somewhere around the world.  For example, 2019-04-02 04:00 in London is 2019-04-01 23:00 in New York.  If you just take hour `4` from London but apply it to the current date in New York, you've created a whole new point in time, a day too early.
- You assume there will be exactly 24 hours in every day.  In time zones that have transitions for daylight saving time or changes in standard time, you may have more or less hours of local time on a the day of the transition.
- In the case of a backward transition, there is a period of ambiguous local time.  For example, when US Pacific Time moves from PDT to PST in November, the hour from 1:00-1:59 is repeated.  If data from both hours are summarized into array element 1, then you will have higher than normal results for that hour.  The opposite is true for forward transitions - you will have an hour with no data.
- The time zone setting of the server can be a fickle thing.  What if you change data centers? What if you move to the cloud? What if you are operating multiple data centers?  What if a server administrator thinks all they are affecting by changing the system time zone is the readout on the taskbar or front panel, etc., and then it affects your application?  In general one should avoid these things by never relying on the server's local time zone setting.

You can avoid all of these problems by basing everything on Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) - especially the array.  Then you can be ignorant of any server time zone setting, and just base everything off the current UTC day, which is the same all over the world.

This will give you the local hour from the given UTC hour in your index:

```js
var localHour = moment.utc({hour: hourIndex}).local().hour();
```

You do not need moment-timezone for the above recommendation.

**However**, if you really feel like you need to convert from a specific time zone to the browser local time, then you would use moment-timezone like this:

```js
var localHour = moment.tz({hour: hourIndex}, timeZoneName).local().hour();
```

Note when you do this, you also have another problem - not every time zone is offset by a whole number of hours.  For example, India uses UTC+05:30.  There are many that are `:30` and a few that are `:45`.  By tracking hours only, you're not providing enough information to properly convert to the correct local hour.  Your results may be off by one.

Comment: Hey, I see all the points you're making, but I actually do need it from the data center's time. For this application, the data center in Hong Kong, let's say, is representative of all the HK user's data. To get their analytics to display anything meaningful for someone in EST, the UTC hours need to be converted to Hong Kong and then into the browser's timezone, correct? Basically if someone in HK is using the app at 3pm, I want someone in EST to see 3pm activity for Hong Kong instead of 3am which is what your `localHour` provides which is just the UTC hour I already provided

Comment: Well, with HK you have the advantage that there is no DST, so all data is simply UTC+8.  But if your original users were in the US, EU, or other places where DST exists, you'd have the problems I described.  It's really much easier to collect and store data in UTC to begin with.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you would do the conversion from local time, and an additional problem you will run into.  Note this is different than what you gave in your question, which converts the wrong direction.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much for the help. You're a time wizard! Luckily I only need data for 5 time zones, and India isn't one of them... a problem for another day

Answer (score 0):

It seems reasonable. And the code should work as long as you have the properly formatted inputs. I like the brevity and clarity of the function.  Any reason you are concerned about reliability?

You might mention in your question that you are using the `moment` and `moment-timezone` packages here to derive your data via its functions (`moment` & `tz`) on this line of code:

```js
return moment(userTime).tz(dataCenterTimeZone).hour();
```

Your function may appear a bit cryptic without the imports in your example for folks reading here to understand, such as :

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
```